# SQL group by school name

Tags: mysql, sql

| school_name | class | medium | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| srk | 1 | english | 13 |
| srk | 2 | english | 14 |
| srk | 3 | english | 15 |
| srk | 1 | french | 16 |
| srk | 2 | french | 16 |
| srk | 3 | french | 18 |
| vrk | 1 | english | 17 |
| vrk | 1 | french | 18 |

I want that output by

| school_name | class1eng | class1french | class2eng | class2french | class3english | class3french |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

[output needed][ otput required

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6RbP.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re looking for multiple select statements along with appropriate cases to satisfy.
This should work for you

```
Select
school_name,
Sum(Case when (class=1 and medium=‘English’) then total else 0 end) as class1english,
Sum(Case when (class=1 and medium=‘French’) then total else 0 end) as class1french,
Sum(Case when (class=2 and medium=‘English’) then total else 0 end) as class2english,
Sum(Case when (class=2 and medium=‘French’) then total else 0 end) as class2french,
Sum(Case when (class=3 and medium=‘English’) then total else 0 end) as class3english,
Sum(Case when (class=3 and medium=‘French’) then total else 0 end) as class3french
From 
table_name
Group by
school_name
```

Comment: Doesn't work for class 2 an class 3

Comment: Works for class 3?

Comment: Doesn't work for both class 2 and 3

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a simple ask, assumed you also want to order your results. Please check below query if that helps

```
SELECT school_name, class, medium, SUM(total) AS Total
FROM <Table Name>
GROUP BY school_name, class, medium
```

Comment: doesnt work i need  row like s srk ,class1eng =13 ,class1french =16 class2eng = 14, class2french=16

Comment: i have added the needed output in image

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for general purpose, complex, but functional.
I've made it for myself as exercise and challenge.

```
/* --------------- TABLE --------------- */
CREATE TABLE schools_tab
(school VARCHAR(9), class INT, subj VARCHAR(9), total INT);
INSERT INTO schools_tab VALUES
('srk', 1, 'english', 13),
('srk', 2, 'english', 14),
('srk', 3, 'english', 15),
('srk', 1, 'french',  16),
('srk', 2, 'french',  16),
('srk', 3, 'french',  18),
('vrk', 1, 'english', 17),
('vrk', 1, 'french',  18);
/* -------------- DYNAMIC QUERY --------------- */
SET @sql=NULL;
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT school, class, subj, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY school) AS idx, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY school) AS ids
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT school FROM schools_tab) A LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT class, subj FROM schools_tab) B ON (1=1)
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT A.ids, A.idx, A.school, A.class, A.subj, COALESCE(B.total, 0) AS total
    FROM cte A LEFT JOIN schools_tab B ON (A.school=B.school AND A.class=B.class AND A.subj=B.subj)
), cte3 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT class, subj 
    FROM schools_tab
    ORDER BY class, subject
)
SELECT CONCAT('WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT school, class, subj, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY school) AS idx, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY school) AS ids
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT school FROM schools_tab) A LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT class, subj FROM schools_tab) B ON (1=1)
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT A.ids, A.idx, A.school, A.class, A.subj, COALESCE(B.total, 0) AS total
    FROM cte A LEFT JOIN schools_tab B ON (A.school=B.school AND A.class=B.class AND A.subj=B.subj)
), ctx AS ('
        'SELECT (SELECT MAX(ids) FROM cte2)  AS n,',
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( '(SELECT total FROM cte2 WHERE idx=',idx,' AND ids=n) AS class',class,subj ) ORDER BY class, subj),
        ' UNION ALL SELECT n-1 AS n,', 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( '(SELECT total FROM cte2 WHERE idx=',idx,' AND ids=n) AS class',class,subj ) ORDER BY class, subj),
        ' FROM ctx WHERE n>0',
        ') SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(''srk,vrk'', '','', n+1), '','', -1) AS school,',
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('class',class,subj)),
        ' FROM ctx ORDER BY school'
        ) INTO @sql
FROM cte2;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```